# Is it possible to run Ethereum Transactions on an arduino?

Tags: arduino, blockchain, ethereum

Is it possible to run Ethereum Transactions on an arduino?
  For instance, if I wanted to switch on an LED light, when the Ethereum transaction has successfully taken place.

Comment: This question is too broad. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 3):

Check out [EthEmbedded](http://ethembedded.com/) which provides binaries and images for multiple IoT devices like Raspberry Pi, Beagle Board, etc.

For Adruino, there is an [experimental library on github](https://github.com/kvhnuke/Ethereum-Arduino). But in general, you can simply clone the [Go](http://gitub.com/ethereum/go-ethereum) or the [Rust](http://github.com/ethcore/parity) client and compile them on any platform. This would allow you to run ethereum transactions also on an arduino.